# NodeJS How to get request object in lambda Serverless Websocket?

Tags: node.js, lambda, websocket, serverless

My client application connects Websocket server with url:
wss://xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx?value=abcd

My websocket server needs to get the value "abcd" passed by client in the request url, however, all I find the I have in my NodeJS server side handler code is:

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
const {
body,
requestContext: {
  connectionId,
  routeKey
}
} = event;
switch (routeKey) {
case '$connect':
......
```

The question is: In my $connect block, how can I get that query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event` is a `APIGatewayProxyEvent` object, then you cant get query parameters from `event` object.

With your case, the code will be like:

```
...
const {
  queryStringParameters, // here
  body,
  requestContext: {
    connectionId,
    routeKey
  }
} = event;

const value = queryStringParameters.value || ''; // value will be `abcd` with url is wss://xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx?value=abcd
...
```